# Wordpress Block Theme: Customize meta viewport

Tags: theme-development

I am building a custom **Block theme** and I need to have this meta viewport in my `<head>` :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

But I couldn't find a hook to customize the default meta viewport outputted in the head :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

The output is coming from this file wp-includes/block-template.php at line 106 :

```
// Add viewport meta tag.
add_action( 'wp_head', '_block_template_viewport_meta_tag', 0 );
```

I tried to remove the action with remove_action somewhere in my theme functions, but without success.

Is this possible via PHP?
If not I guess I'll have to do it with Javascript (replace the DOM element).

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason `remove_action` shouldn't work. What's the code you actually tried? Also, why do you need to add this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. If you managed to do this, could you please tell us how?

@Jacob: For obvious reasons: Because we need a different behaviour on mobile devices.

Comment: @SebastianStarke Obviously, but the behaviour of the viewport Max wanted to add is bad for accessibility and user hostile: https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/never-use-maximum-scale/

Comment: @Jacob Peattie: Maybe he has a use case in which it makes sense. A web app for example, in which he wants to handle zoom all by himself. I for one want to limit the zoom to factor 2, because of stuff that is entirely my own problem. Can't you guys just focus on the question?

Comment: @SebastianStarke You brought it up! I already addressed the question. There's no reason `remove_action` shouldn't work.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie I know, but somehow it doesn't. As stated in the original question. I can confirm that.

Comment: To use remove_action on this you need to do it inside the wp_head action per instructions here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53743#comment:2